# What will be the value of n?

Tags: logarithms

$$
\log_{10}2 = \frac{1}{n} \times \log_{10}n\,
$$

Can anybody please help me finding the value of *n* ?

**Sorry for earlier typo..Edited the questions**

Comment: After getting $3$ answers, you cannot just simply change the question..  Its not a good thing to do. And moreover you need to put this info regarding the typo in each answerers comment box, else they might not know about the change you made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simplifies to $n=\log_{2}(n)$, so $2^{n}=n$. This equation cannot be solved algebraically but has a solution in terms of the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)$W$:

$$n=-\frac{W_m(-\log(2))}{\log(2)}$$

Comment: There was a typo..Please give answer now

Comment: I resolved the problem.

Comment: I actually got an algorithm question where it is asked that if algorithm A has run time complexity of 8N^2 and B has an complexity of 64*n*lg n (base 2) then for what value of n, B will give lesser value of complexity.

Comment: If I were asked that question, I'd assume exact answers were unnecessary and that something like $50$ would be fine lol.

Comment: Since $xe^x\ge-\frac1e$ for real $x$, and $-\log(2)\lt-\frac1e$, $\mathrm{W}(-\log(2))$ cannot be real.

Comment: It also seems that this answer is off by a factor of $-1$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $$\log_{10}2=\frac{1}{n}\times \log_{10}n$$
$$n\log_{10}2=\log_{10}n$$
$$\log_{10}2^{n}=\log_{10}n$$
$$2^{n}=n$$

Comment: There was a typo..Please give answer now

Answer (score 1):

For real $n$,
$$
\frac{\log(n)}{n}\le\frac1e\lt\log(2)\tag{1}
$$
so there is no real solution.

---

We can find complex solutions. If
$$
\log(2)=\frac1n\log(n)\tag{2}
$$
then
$$
-\log(2)=\frac1n\log\left(\frac1n\right)=\log\left(\frac1n\right)e^{\log\left(\frac1n\right)}\tag{3}
$$
Thus, if
$$
n=e^{-W(-\log(2))}\tag{4}
$$
for any branch of the [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n\log(n)
&=\overbrace{-W(-\log(2))\vphantom{e^W}}^{\log(n)}\overbrace{e^{W(-\log(2))}}^{\frac1n}\\
&=-(-\log(2))\\[4pt]
&=\log(2)\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Since $n=\frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)}$, we also have
$$
n=\frac{-W(-\log(2))}{\log(2)}\tag{6}
$$
Therefore, we can use either $(4)$ or $(6)$ to compute $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Re-arranging your expression (after considering the typo), we have $$\log_{10}2=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \log_{10}n$$
or, $$n\log_{10}2=\log_{10}n$$
or, $$\log_{10}2^{n}=\log_{10}n$$
or, $$2^{n}=n$$

But the graphs of the equations $y=2^{x}$ and $y=x$ never intersect. So there are no real solutions for $n$ in this equation.

Comment: There was a typo..Please give answer now

Comment: @MayukhSarkar Corrected accordingly.